# Не работает \p{L} в регулярном выражении

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Имеется регулярное выражение:

```
$d = preg_quote($domain);
$m = "([\\p{L}\\p{N}-]+)";
$k = "([\\p{L}\\p{N}-]+)";
preg_match("/^".$d."/{$m}/{$k}\$/u", $request, $match)
```

этот участок кода отвечает за разбор url - если он соответствует регулярному выражению - выполняются определённые действия.
Проблема в том, что он "пропускает" только английские символы.
Если попытаться подсунуть URL вида 
[http://domen.xyz/page-de/tüitleü](http://domen.xyz/page-de/t%C3%BCitle%C3%BC)
или
[http://domen.ru/page-ru/новость15](http://domen.ru/page-ru/%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C15)
т.е. с русскими, немецкими, францускими буквами - уже не пропускает.

В чем может быть проблема и как её можно решить?
Версия PHP на сервере 5.6.24

И ещё, на крайний случай, если составить корректную регулярку не удастся, можно использовать такой вариант:

```
[^!\$\<\>\(\)\+=@^%\:\;]+
```

т.е. просто исключить все символы, которых не должно быть в URL. Как он в плане безопасности и быстродействия будет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php

$request = "http://domen.xyz/page-de/tüitleü";
$domain = "http://domen.xyz";

$d = preg_quote($domain, '/');
$m = "([\\p{L}\\p{N}-]+)";
$k = "([\\p{L}\\p{N}-]+)";
preg_match("/^{$d}\/{$m}\/{$k}$/u", $request, $match);

echo '<pre>'."\n";
var_dump($match);
echo '</pre>'."\n";
```

Результат:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(34) "http://domen.xyz/page-de/tüitleü"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "page-de"
  [2]=>
  string(9) "tüitleü"
}
```

Ваши ошибки:

1. Функция [preg_quote()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-quote.php) не экранирует слеши по умолчанию.
2. Вы экранировали символ обозначающий конец строки.
3. Вы не экранировали слеши в регулярке.

Comment: Спасибо! И ещё я совсем забыл, что буквы отличные от английских приходят из url в скрипт виде %C3%B6. Проблему решила функция urldecode() + я исправил указанные Вами ошибки. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

https://regex101.com/r/jS9lT9/1 вот все работает, не понимаю зачем вы двойные слэши ставите [\p{L}\p{N}-]+

Comment: Двойные слэши - это правильно, ведь иначе в строке появится неопределённая escape-последовательность. Хотя ПХП с такими справляется, т.е. все обратные слэши в неизвестных  escape-последовательностях обрабатываются как буквальные слэши - то, что для регэкспа нужно. [*``\\`` обратная косая черта... экранирование любого символа выведет также и саму обратную косую черту.*](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)